# How add a request item to Backpack-Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

I have to pass the secret **author_id** of the user when he edit for example an Article and memorize that into the Database in Backpack-Laravel.
How can do that?

I be able to do just this, the value appears in the **$request** array (I use dd($request) for know that) but isn't stored on the database.

**AuthorCrudController.php**

```
public function update(UpdateArticleRequest $request)
{
    //dd($request); <-- author_id = Auth::id()
    return parent::updateCrud();
}
```

**UpdateArticleRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{

    $this->request->add(['author_id'=> Auth::id()]);
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
        'author_id' => 'numeric'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99 times out of 100, when the value isn't stored it's because that column hasn't been mentioned in your model's `$fillable` property. Is this it?

---

Sidenote: Adding the author_id like this works, but if you're using this approach for multiple models, I recommend coding it once for all your models. I use a trait for this. That way, any time an entry is created, the author is saved and you have the have all the methods for getting it in one place, the trait (`$this->creator()`, `this->updator`).

My approach to this is this:

1) I have two new columns in my database `created_by` and `updated_by`

2) I use a trait like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait CreatedByTrait {

    /**
     * Stores the user id at each create & update.
     */
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {

        if (\Auth::check())
        {
            if (!isset($this->created_by) || $this->created_by=='') {
                $this->created_by = \Auth::user()->id;
            }

            $this->updated_by = \Auth::user()->id;
        }

        parent::save();
    }


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by');
    }

    public function updator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'updated_by');
    }
}
```

3) Whenever I want a model to have this feature, i just need to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;

class Car extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use CreatedByTrait; // <---- add this line
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No unfortunately, the '$fillable' property is present as well as the 'use CrudTrait;' that I had previously forgotten :/ I do not know why I can not update or store that parameter.

Comment: Hmm... Then maybe try adding it in the AuthorCrudController::update() method, not in the FormRequest?

Comment: Or you could use Backpack for this, and add a hidden field with that value as default.

Comment: I tried to do this: (but don't work)
 ` public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $this->setAuthorId($request);

        return parent::updateCrud();
    }

    protected function setAuthorId(Request $request) {
        $request->add(['author_id'=> "1"]);
    }`

Comment: A hidden field should work fine: https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#hidden

Comment: Yes it 's true, but I don't want that anyone can changing this parameter.

Comment: Then I guess the best way to proceed would be to create a mutator in you model, like I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

The update function in my backpack setup has $request passed in updateCrud function. The one that you have mentioned does not have the request passed into the parent function.

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
    // your additional operations before save here
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    return $redirect_location;
}
```